Incidence Geometry and projective plane

Consider an interpretation of incidence geometry $(P,L,I)$, where $P \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, $L \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ and $I = \{(p,l) \in P \times L : pl \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Is this interpretation a projective plane?

The three axioms says

Any two points are contained in a unique line
Any two lines are contain a unique point
There are four points, no three of which are in a line

I am not sure if I interpreted this model and check the axioms correctly. But here is my attempt to go over every axiom. I'd like some feedback on whether I answered this problem correctly.

For when $l_1 = 1$, we can see that the points on this line are $p = \{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \cdots\}$. Similarly when $l_2 = 2$, we see that the points on this line are $p = \{ \pm 1/2, \pm 2/2 , \cdots\}$. So it is obvious that $p = -1, 1$ are not uniquely contained in a unique line. So it does not satisfy this axiom.

Using the same example, for $l_1$ and $l_2$, points $p = 1, -1$ are two points contained in both lines. So it also does not satisfy this axiom.

Take the points $p = 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5$ are points in $l_2, l_3, l_4, l_5$ respectively defined in a similar manner as above. Then these are four points but no three of them are in a line. So this axiom is satisfied.


Hence, it is not a model of projective plane.

(1)) You could have stopped after checking that the first axiom isn't satisfied. A projective plane has to satisfy all of the axioms, so as soon as one axiom fails, you know that you don't have a projectiive plane.   (2) In your discussion of the third axiom, all four of the points $p$ that you proposed are on the line $l_{60}$.

@AndreasBlass Thanks. Although the question didn't ask, I still wanted to check to see if I understood each axiom in cases like my discussion about axiom 3.
I guess $1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5$ are on line $l_{60}$ because $lcm(2,3,4,5) = 60$.  Any way, it seems like then axiom 3 should $\textbf{not}$ be satisfied. Because I can use a similar argument like the one above using LCM?

A similar argument using LCM will work when the points $p$ are rational numbers, or rational multiples of each other. But no line contains three of the four points $1, \sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt5$.

@AndreasBlass I see. So line $l = 141421356237...$ will contain $p = \sqrt{2}$, line $l = 22360679775...$ will contain $p = \sqrt{5}$ and so on... Hence the axiom is then indeed satisfied.

@AndreasBlass Looking at this problem again, I am a little skeptical. Does the point $\sqrt{2}$ even lie on any line in this model?

The point $p=\sqrt2$ lies on the line $l=\sqrt2$, because $pl=2$ is an integer.

Answering my own question, this interpretation is not a projective plane as it fails axioms 1 and 2. Axiom 3 is satisfied if we consider $p = 1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}$ as hinted by @AndreasBlass. Thank you.
